# Jquery - How to access this element after I click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to access this element after I click this button... 
after so many tries still don't know how to do this... this is my example... because I want to try this method http://jsfiddle.net/yXcZG/53/ but in my own way...

```
<div id="modalBodyContact" class="modal-body">
   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="display" id="contactsTable">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <p data-id="5" class="contactInfo">123321</p>
            </td>
            <td class="pull-right">
                <button data-id="5" class="edit" type="button">Edit</button>
                <button data-id="5" class="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <p data-id="6" class="contactInfo">123321</p> <---- I get this element after I click that EDIT BUTTON
            </td>
            <td class="pull-right">
                <button data-id="6" class="edit" type="button">Edit</button> // <---- I CLICK THIS then ACCESS to <p>
                <button data-id="6" class="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

and this is what I do when I click button...

```
$("#modalBodyContact").on('click', 'button.edit', function(){
   var contact_id   = $(this).data("id");
//im stuck here
});
```

EDIT 1

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ce7t1/5

I want to return `<p data-id="5" class="contactInfo">5555</p>` not the `5555`... how to do that? cause I want to replace it with textbox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED]

In your function "TBox", the parameter "obj" is not an object, is a string, so you need to pass the object and not the string. I've change your code again to accept objects, please take a look http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ce7t1/6/

```
$("#modalBodyContact").on('click', 'button.edit', function(){
  var contact_id   = $(this).data("id");
  var p = $("#modalBodyContact").find("p[data-id='" + contact_id + "']");
  console.log(p);
  TBox(p);
});
```

Comment: hello I want to return <p data-id="5" class="contactInfo">5555</p> not the 5555... how to do that? cause I want to replace it with textbox..

Comment: Is that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ce7t1/2/ (I've edited the answer by the way).

Comment: wait... do you know why I got `               ` ? I have blank space... like 8 spaces...

Comment: look on my http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ce7t1/5/ it can't find `id` because of those blank spaces...

Comment: In your function "TBox", the paramenter "obj" is not an object, is a string, so you need to pass the object and not the string. I've change your code again to accept objects, please take a look http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ce7t1/6/

Comment: sorry for wasting time... but all that I've done is actually not actually working on ajax... so .find() is not working on the ajax get... please help... T_T

Comment: What ajax get? Maybe you need to include more code to let me understand the error. Have you tried my last changes?

Comment: look on `line 44` on this http://jsfiddle.net/w2nscncu/1/ it return nothing but when I put already the html it works...

Comment: You haven't include the data-id into the p. I've moved the click events inside the $.ajax callback. Check it now. http://jsfiddle.net/w2nscncu/3/

Comment: You're welcome, by the way, I've edited your question adding the jsfiddle link. It's better for everyone to understand the problem. If you want you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate onclick event on button then get its attribute by `this` then do

```
  $("button.edit").on('click', function(){
   var contact_id   = $(this).attr("data-id");
   var text   = $(".contactInfo[data-id="+contact_id+"]").text();

   alert("id is "+contact_id+" text is"+text);

});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/wgxLwkwh/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$("#modalBodyContact").on('click', 'button.edit', function () {
    console.log($(this).parents('tr').find("p[data-id='" + $(this).data("id") + "']").text());
});
```

**[Working JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/Lh102wvL/)**

Comment: hello I want to return `<p data-id="5" class="contactInfo">5555</p>` not the `5555`... how to do that? cause I want to replace it with textbox...